# Disable Action Extensions in NSTextView on OS X

Tags: cocoa, osx-yosemite, nstextview, appkit

Is there a way to completely disable the action extensions in `NSTextView` which were introduced in OS X Yosemite? See the example in the following figure:

[image]

I haven't found any info about this - neither in the documentation nor in the Yosemite release notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new property on `NSTextView` in OS X Yosemite called `usesRolloverButtonForSelection`. Setting it to `false` disables the action extensions menu.

```
@availability(OSX, introduced=10.10)
var usesRolloverButtonForSelection: Bool
// Controls whether to show rollover button for extension service items inside text selection. It's enabled by default.
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the `allowsContextMenuPlugIns` property of the menu to `NO`? That has helped here for similar issues with menu additions, albeit not Yosemite extensions.